# Top-level Await Node 17 & TypeScript nightly

Tags: node.js, typescript, async-await

I have a simple script trying to test out top level await with Node & TypeScript.

```
import { readFile } from "fs/promises";

async function getNum(filename: string) {
  return parseInt(await readFile(filename, "utf8"), 10);
}

try {
  const numberPromises = [1, 2, 3].map((i) => getNum(`${i}.txt`));
  const numbers = await Promise.all(numberPromises);
  console.log(numbers[0], numbers[1], numbers[2]);
} catch (err) {
  console.error("Something went wrong");
  console.error(err);
}
```

I get this error when I try to compile with TypeScript:

> error TS1378: Top-level 'await' expressions are only allowed when the 'module' option is set to 'es2022', 'esnext', 'system', or 'nodenext', and the 'target' option is set to 'es2017' or higher.

It's triggered by the top-level await on line9:

> const numbers = await Promise.all(numberPromises);

I'm confused because I have done both of the things mentioned in the error message and I have tried to pair down my `tsconfig.json` as much as possible.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es2022",
    "target": "es2017",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "Node"
  }
}
```

I also have `type: module` in my package.json file.

```json
{
  "name": "ts-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^17.0.5",
    "typescript": "^4.6.0-dev.20211226"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node dist/script.js",
    "compile": "tsc script.ts"
  },
  "author": "Todd Matthews",
  "license": "ISC",
  "volta": {
    "node": "17.3.0"
  }
}
```

Any help on how I could test out top-level await with Node and TypeScript would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think you can try to set module: 'commonjs' in tsconfig.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll provide a simpler reproduction case for you which doesn't rely on any filesystem API, and I'll include all repo files and commands:

### Files

`./package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "so-70491077",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "dist/main.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "tsc && node dist/main.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^4.5.4"
  }
}
```

`./tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es2022",
    "target": "es2017",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "Node"
  },
  "files": ["main.ts"]
}
```

`./main.ts`:

```ts
export async function getRandom (): Promise<number> {
  return Math.random();
}

const n = await getRandom();
console.log(n);
```

### Commands

```
cd /path/to/the/dir/where/you/stored/the/files/above
npm i
npm test
```

### Output

```
> so-70491077@1.0.0 test
> tsc && node dist/main.js

0.9303778211654203 # a similar floating point number
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code and the `tsconfig.json` are fine. But tsc doesn't use `tsconfig.json` file. From the doc [What is a tsconfig.json](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html):

> When input files are specified on the command line, `tsconfig.json` files are ignored.

So, don't specify the input files for the `compile` npm script.

```json
"scripts": {
   "compile": "tsc"
}
```

Comment: Note that the input files can still be specified in the configuration file itself